# How to place table layout below Linear layout programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my code to display table layout below linear layout.here i am setting scroll view as contentview.but only table layout displaying on screen.here any problem in layout.please help me thanks.

```
 ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            Button btn1 = new Button(this);
            btn1.setText("Button1");
            ll.addView(btn1);
            btn1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            TableLayout resultLayout = new TableLayout(this);
            resultLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
            resultLayout.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
```

Here tried by placing the linear layout above the table layout now only linearlayout displaying

```
 LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        // Set the TextView for the Question
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv1.setText("HI");
        ll.addView(tv1);
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
        TableLayout resultLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        resultLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
        resultLayout.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
```

//Here i have table rows code

```
ll.addView(scrollView);
setContentView(ll);
```

now setting linear layout as contentview as per your answers scroll view contains only table layout.but why it is not displaying in the screen

Comment: Is Linear Layout is your parent Layout??

Comment: Here..You can't add two Views in Scroll View... Because Scroll View can host only one child View.

Comment: have you add table layout to Linear layout??

Comment: Added table layout to scrollview then added this scrollview to LL

Comment: have you set layout params of Linear layout to Scroll View and Table layout???

Comment: No.......?????????????how to do it?

Comment: you have to set ...........

Comment: tv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); something like this.

Comment: added linearlayout,table layout and scrollview in the question ,could you please arrange it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37380/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-prabha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this:\

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext()); 
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 
ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 

// Set the TextView for the Question 
TextView tv1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext()); 
tv1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
tv1.setText("HI"); 
ll.addView(tv1); 
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this); 
scrollView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
TableLayout resultLayout = new TableLayout(this); 
resultLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
scrollView.addView(resultLayout);   
resultLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true); 
resultLayout.setShrinkAllColumns(true); 
ll.addView(scrollView);
```

Answer (score 1):

`ScrollView`s in android should contain only a single child. So might I suggest you add a `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView` and then add the other components in this `LinearLayout`